# Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist using sendMessage/onMessage

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Using the new api sendMessage/onMessage to send messages instead of sendRequest/onRequest i'm getting the following error in the JS console : `Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.`

And I can't understand were it's coming since it was working with the old API.

Here is some sample :

```
//content.js
 chrome.extension.sendMessage({index: number}, function(response) {   
     console.log("test", response.data);                          
 });                                                              



//background.js
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    // From content script.                                                 
    if (sender.tab) {
     //stuff
    }
    sendResponse({who: "me",data: "tata"}); 
});
```

Any ideas ? 
thx

Comment: First of all - your listener function should return true to make sendResponse() work. BTW maybe your background.js isn't working at all?

Comment: What do you mean by isn't working at all ??

Comment: I mean it is not loaded.

Comment: it's unlikely since it worked with the old API.

Answer (score 0):

sendMessage/onMessage doesn't support in before 20.x.x.x version of chrome. So you need to use sendRequest/onRequest by detecting browser version. you can detect chrome browser version via this line of code. (parseInt(navigator.userAgent.match(/Chrom(e|ium)/([0-9]+)./)[2]) > 20)

Comment: It's exactly the opposite. sendMessage/onMessage is present on Chrome 20+. See http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/whats_new.html#20

Comment: ohhh yes Matthieu there should be before instead of after ... :)

Comment: since i'm running on chrome 21, it should not be a problem for me then.

Answer (score 0):

@Matthieu I can confirm that onMessage/sendMessage works only starting from Chrome 20+, Chromium supports them even on older versions (I can't remember from which one, sorry). However, if you get this kind of error, probably you have some error that prevents Chorme for loading the background page or, if your script tries to grab data via content scripts, you probably have the console focused, instead of a normal tab. Usually it's this last one the problem.

@rkp If you want to detect whether your browser has sendMessage/sendRequest and their respectively onMessage/onRequest, just to check for `chrome.extension.hasOwnProperty('onMessage')` or `chrome.extension['onMessage']`. If they are false, surely your browser will support onRequest/sendRequest only. The same is true whether you test for the presence of sendRequest/onRequest.

Comment: Is this an answer or should this be two separate comments?

Comment: It's my answer to confirm which versions supports the methods, why this error can appear in extensions, and the correct way to identify these methods into the extensions without relying on `userClient` and RegExp. The mentions have been added only to clarify the references of my answer. If they make confusion in my answer I'll remove'em.